# How to convert .png to bitmap (.bmp) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vector, printing, bitmap

I am having difficulties converting a png file of simple black-coloured patterns I made using Illustrator into a bitmap. I need to do this in order to 3D print it (vector printer).

I was instructed to use MATLAB to do it however I tried using imread and imwrite but I'm rather confused as to what the first argument of imwrite, A, should be? Is there a particular format I need to use for it to work?

I tried doing it with an online converter and it gave me the same exact image but of type .bmp. Is that what's meant to happen?

I would appreciate any insight on the problem.

Comment: Hi @mamajava, I'm just wondering if I have solved your problem.

Comment: Yes :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [imread](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) to read your png, then [imwrite](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#inputarg_fmt) to save it in bmp format.

Implementation:

```
pic = imread('mypic.png');
imwrite(pic,'mypic.bmp','bmp');
```